# Loop through visible cells with deletion, but not skipping rows in the process

Tags: excel, vba

I am looping through only the visible cells in a filtered table's first column. Where I have indicated deletion in a listbox on a Userform, I want to delete the row. The problem is that deletion in essence skips the next visible cell jumping down one row essentially. How do I delete rows without missing them in my loop?

```
For Each cl In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Range("Table1[[#All],[First Column]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If (ListBox2.Selected(a)) Then
        cl.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    a = a + 1
Next cl
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Option Explicit is recommended
TRY this Macro

```
Option Explicit
Sub del_rows()
Dim ar As Range
Dim x%, t%, y%, a%: a = 0
Dim My_Val 'choose the value of My_Val
For Each cl In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Range("Table1[[#All],[First Column]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    x = cl.Areas.Count
      For t = x To 1 Step -1
         For y = 1 To Areas(t).Rows.Count
          If (ListBox2.Selected(a)) = My_Val Then
          cel.EntireRow.Delete
          End If
           a = a + 1
          Next y
          a = 0
    Next x
  Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. There were however some fundamental flaws with your code:
 - ar was not used.
 - My question is not based on a value (My_Val), but whether the item is selected (boolean)
 - t and y remained at a value of 1 throughout the loop.
 - cl vs. cel would cause an error as the variable wasn't created and "Option Explicit" selected.

I did however figure out a way. Please refer to my answer posted.

Thank you however for taking the time and challenging my school of thought. I really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing:

```
Sub Answer()
    'Delete selected from Listbox2
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim a As Integer

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete all lines selected?", vbYesNo, "Delete selected?") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    a = 0
    x = 0

    For Each cl In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Range("Table1[[#All],[First Column]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If (ListBox2.Selected(a)) And (a <> 0) Then
            ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
            myArray(x) = cl.Address
            x = x + 1
        End If
        a = a + 1
        If a = ListBox2.ListCount Then Exit For
    Next cl

    For x = UBound(myArray) To LBound(myArray) Step -1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Range(myArray(x)).EntireRow.Delete
    Next x
End sub
```